# Floated element not included in parent, causing margin-bottom problems

Tags: html, css, margin

Right, so I've got a section of a page:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="author">
        <img src="images/officers/john_q_public_thm.jpg" />
        <span class="name">John Q. Public</span>
        <span class="position">President</span>
    </div>
    <abbr class="postdate">
        <span class="month m-01">Jan</span>
        <span class="day d-31">31</span>
        <span class="year y-2009">2009</span>
    </abbr>
    <div class="content">
                <h2 class="title">Article Title</h2>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi...facilisis luctus, metus</p>
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi...facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="article">...</div>
<div class="article">...</div>
```

The `author` and `abbr` divs are floated to the left. Each one of these `article` divs needs to be separated from its siblings by 5px or so. However, the `author` div is extending beyond the technical "height" of the div. The `margin-bottom` is doing nothing, as the space is being taken up by the floated `author`.

This is somewhat difficult to envision, so I've placed it on [a server](http://jenkskeyclub.org/test/).

Is there any way to force the parent to be at least as tall as all of the floated elements within?

If anyone figures out what I'm saying, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this at the bottom/inside of the div.article (right before closing the div)

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Or do this:

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/
```

Comment: The sitepoint link was the most semantic way to do it, imo. I *hate* adding elements to the DOM if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above hacks, you can set `overflow:auto;` on the `article` divs, although this might have side effects depending on what other rules you have on those divs. But it prevents you having to add elements to the HTML.

Comment: You are correct, but vinhboy was first with the correct answer. (the sitepoint link)

Comment: Ah, so he did. No worries, I'll leave this to point it out instead of having to copy/paste a URL and search through an article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clearing element after your floating elements.
Something like this usually works `<br clear="both"/>` which will clear both left and right floats and "pad out" your containing element.

You can specify `both`, `left` and `right` which clear all floating elements, left floating and right floating accordingly.